# How to find whether a multiplicative group is cyclic or not

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am new to group theory, and I observed that some multiplicative mod-n groups are cyclic and some are not . For ex :

$U(8) = (1,3,5,7)$ is not cyclic , but

$U(10) = (1,3,7,9)$ is cyclic and its generators are $(1,3,9)$.

How do we find which multiplicative group is cyclic, which is not?

Comment: Hint: Using the Chinese remainder theorem you can reduce your problem to the case that $n$ is a prime power (for $m,n$ coprime $(Z/(mn))^\times = (Z/m)^\times\times(Z/n)^\times$)) and $(Z/p^k)^\times$ is cyclic unless $p=2$ and $k\ge 2$.

Comment: @j.p. Right, this is exactly how the answer (at the duplicate) starts:)